# Contains + startswith in jquery selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I need to select elements depending on first letter of text value of a tag.
For example:

```
<li><label for="1"><input type="checkbox" name="contacts" value="1">Aaron</label></li>
<li><label for="2"><input type="checkbox" name="contacts" value="2">Born</label></li>
<li><label for="3"><input type="checkbox" name="contacts" value="3">Bale</label></li>
<li><label for="4"><input type="checkbox" name="contacts" value="4">Kate</label></li>
```

And I want to select all inputs that text value starts with B - in result it should be Born and Bale inputs. How can I do this using jQuery/pure javascript?

Comment: That is not how you format labels for inputs. The `for` value of the label must be the `id` value of the input.

Comment: I have tried to implement alphabetical filter. If users clicks on hyperlink with appropriate letter he will see only checkboxes with text that starts with letter from hyperlink value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/bb2uE/

Html:

```
<label for="1">Aaron</label><input type="checkbox" name="contacts" value="1"></li>
<li><label for="2">Born</label><input type="checkbox" name="contacts" value="2"></li>
<li><label for="3">Bale</label><input type="checkbox" name="contacts" value="3"></li>
<li><label for="4">Kate</label><input type="checkbox" name="contacts" value="4"></li>
```

​Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var obj = [];
    $.each($('label'), function(){
        if ($(this).html().charAt(0) == 'B')
         obj.push($(this).html());       
    });
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++)
        console.log(obj[i]);
});
```

Or, if you want to hide those inputs: http://jsfiddle.net/bb2uE/1/

Javascript:

```
var hideFunction = function(letter){
   $.each($('label'), function(){
        if ($(this).html().charAt(0) == letter)
            $(this).parent().hide();     
    });
}
hideFunction('B');
```

Comment: How can pass letter parameter in each function, so it won't be hardcoded?

Answer (score 1):

Your markup should look like this:

```
<li><input type="checkbox" name="contacts" id="id1" value="1"><label for="id1">Aaron</label></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="contacts"  id="id2"  value="2"><label for="id2">Born</label></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="contacts"  id="id3"  value="3"><label for="id3">Bale</label></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="contacts"  id="id4" value="4"><label for="id4">Kate</label></li>​
```

and this is how you get your input

```
$("label").filter(function () {
    return $(this).text().charAt(0) === "B"; 
}).closest("li").find("input");
```